# can't get an answer from passthru

Tags: javascript, php, passthru

This is a simple php code

```
<?php
ob_start(passthru('/usr/bin/env node getResult.js '));
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
//  console shows Data as String but $data is still empty
    echo "Data : " . $data;
?>
```

And the node.js script just has a variable result with an object in it.

```
console.log("skript startet");
var get = function(){
/*do stuff to get variable*/
        result = "test;
        console.log(result);
        return result;
      });
    });
};
get();
```

Problem: I need the variable in the getResult.js script but I cant' catch it in php. Any Ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

Why bother with the output buffer at all?

```
exec( '/usr/bin/env node getResult.js', $data );
echo "Data: " . $data;
```

[`exec()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.exec.php) writes the complete output of the command into the provided variable.

Comment: If I use this , my scripts doesn't start anymore :/

Comment: Just putting the echo first, and then the passthru (with no buffering) would also work

Comment: @ChrisLear That doesn't place the result in the variable, which is the actual goal. The echo is most probably only a test.

Comment: If it's not running, try wrapping it in `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: @Isabell what's the error you get when it doesn't start?

Comment: @GeraldSchneider fair point about the variable, assuming that is the actual goal

Comment: no error I placed a console.log in my script with "started" just to see if this worked. And the console doesn't show this anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
<?php
ob_start(); //note, no parameter here
passthru('/usr/bin/env node getResult.js '); // this should be captured
$data = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

echo "Data : " . $data;
?>
```

Comment: $data is still empty but script gets executed

Comment: you mean the getResult.js script is executed? What is the output of that js script? And what is the output of the php script?

Comment: php script is all what you see here, node script makes an mongodb call gets some data , i wrote it into a var and now i need the content of this war in my php code.

Comment: Sounds like the node script doesn't actually output anything. Can you run it from the command line? What output do you get? Is it actually emitting the value of the variable?

Comment: ofc I checked this if i log the result variable in my script , I see that its filled with data

Comment: Sure, but does the node script actually print that data to `stdout`? In other words, is there a line like `console.log(data);`? Sorry to ask questions that might seem daft, but you keep talking about a javascript variable as though php can access its value directly. Which it can't.